# How to Find out a GNU Screen Window’s Default Directory?

Tags: gnu-screen, working-directory

#### Question

How do I find out the default directory of a window in GNU screen?

NB: I’m *not* looking for the current directory of the *process* running in the window.

#### Background

I have created a [`hardcopy`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Hardcopy) of my scrollback buffer without giving an absolute path. Now I don’t know where to find the created file. I don’t remeber from which directory I have originally invoked `screen` and I haven’t used any [`chdir` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Chdir).

I’m now wondering which directory I have polluted with my hardcopy … :-\

Comment: Does `C-a` `:` for command line mode and then `exec pwd` help?

Comment: Yes, a quick test shows that `:exec pwd` actually works. @thrig why don't you write that up as an answer?

Comment: @thrig Thanks, that’s useful! You should post that as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is probably to just make a new window, it will start in the directory where screen was started by default.

Alternatives include looking at the process' `cwd` (e.g. `/proc/<pid>/cwd`, but this requires root as screen is setuid)

Note that you can change that directory with `C-a :chdir <path>` later

Comment: More often than not, `screen` isn't running setuid-root.

Comment: It's almost always setuid something (usually group bit), that's enough to make the /proc cwd link unreadable from very quick testing on debian (jessie), redhat (el7) and archlinux (arch is real setuid root). There's much better alternatives, I hadn't thought of :exec :)

Comment: What's `/proc`? ;-)  Even though the OP *might* be running on Linux, there's nothing saying he's actually *is*.

Comment: Good point, I guess they can use `procstat` or `lsof` then. Hard to give specifics without details, but there are ways to find a process' cwd from their PID on all unixes that I know about - let's just say it's left as an exercice to the reader :P

Answer (score 4):

By using Screen's `exec` command to execute the `pwd` utility, you will get the working directory for the current `screen` instance.

It will not be the current working directory of the shell/whatever running in the `screen` session (if you have used `cd` to change directory of that shell) since the environment of the `screen` process was created when it started, and the `pwd` utility will be executed out of *that* environment.

So, in `screen`, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> followed by `:exec pwd` to see the directory name.